# How to assign $localize dynamically to a text imported from environment file?

Tags: angular, internationalization

I have a text which I would like to translate. The Text is saved in environment file as a value in a json object. Something like:

```
myObject: {
   Key1: 'value1',
   Key2: 'value2',
   Key3: 'value3'
}
```

So I'am trying to use `$localize` feature for dynamic translation in `*.component.ts` file for this text. Therefore I go for the following concept/idea:

```
ngOnInit(){
    ....
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(myObject)) {
        console.log(`key=${key} value=${$localize} :@@Text${key}:${value}`);
        return `${key}: ${$localize} :@@listColumn${key}:${value}`;
    }
}
```

This should generate and give me following back:

```
myObject: {
    key1: $localize ':@@TextKey1:value1',
    key2: $localize ':@@TextKey2:value2',
    key3: $localize ':@@TextKey3:value3'
}
```

in the other hand I do have the specific trnalsation files which contains these keys:

```
    <unit id="TextKey1">
       <segment>
           <source>value1</source>
           <target>valeur1</target>
       </segment>
   </unit>
   <unit id="TextKey2">
       <segment>
           <source>value2</source>
           <target>valeur2</target>
       </segment>
   </unit>
   ....
```

Till that stage everythings looks good and execute without issues. But when trying to bind the translated text in the view, I get following error in the dev console:

> key=key1 value=function () {
> throw new Error('It looks like your application or one of its dependencies is using i18n.\n' + 'Angular 9 introduced a global `$localize()` function that needs to be loaded.\n' + 'Please run `ng add @angular/localize` from the Angular CLI.\n' + '(For non-CLI projects, add `import \'@angular/localize/init\';` to your `polyfills.ts` file.\n' + 'For server-side rendering applications add the import to your `main.server.ts` file.)');
> } :@@TextKey1:value1

The `polyfills.ts` already contains: `import '@angular/localize/init';` I do also have dynamic translation using: `$localize` in other components and works straith forward. Just for the one above not.

What I am trying to reach at the end is to provide a translation for some values/text saved in environment file which I pass to the view/HTML. They are saved as **javascript object** So therefore I import these values into `*.component.ts` file from `environment`, assign them the `$localize` keyword so that they can be dynamically translatable and then output the correct translation in the HTML.

The reason behind that is that these text/values in enviroment can be changed any time.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work. Basically what `$localize` does is look at the content of your `.ts` file and search for `$localize` calls. Any dynamic (runtime) stuff going on, like dynamic localized keys are not going to be found by the localizer.

Bottomline, you will always have to write the localize key. If you expand your question, or ask a new question on what you are actually trying to achieve with your dynamic translations, I might be able to help you.

Comment: Question has been enhanced. If it's not clear enough and you don't mind, we can continue in the chat. Cheers! And I did expect that it might not work the way I tried it. But I thought I might have missed something.

Comment: @k.vincent if a translation, and or text/value changes in the environment, it will require a new build of the application. Your only way is to declare the possible translation keys in a separate object and use some key to access these. This way you will be able to get the translation working, but this will require you to have a known set of possible text/values and their translations

Comment: To be honest, can't follow your approach. A code example would be very helpful!